# Bootstrap's selectpicker() title contains HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

We are using Bootstrap's selectpicker() with data-icon defined. Here is our HTML code:

```
<select class="selectpickerLang" name="language" id="id_language">
<option value="en-us" data-icon="icon-en-us">English, United States</option>
<option value="en-gb" data-icon="icon-en-gb">English, United Kingdom</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpickerLang').selectpicker();
});
```

(in some cases we have more locales).

The problem is that the title of the button (tested with Google Chrome) contains HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="id_language" title="&lt;i class=&quot;glyphicon icon-en-us&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; English, United States"><span class="filter-option pull-left"><i class="glyphicon icon-en-us"></i> English, United States</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

You can see the title is "`<i class="glyphicon icon-en-us"></i> English, United States`". The correct title is "`English, United States`".

We are using Bootstrap version 2.3.2, but I think this feature is created by bootstrap-select version 1.4.2. Has it been fixed in future versions?